# How to display database data to your website?

Tags: django

This is a very simple question that got me stuck. I have 2 tables that are connected: Dealershiplistings, Dealerships. On my website I need to display the Model, Make and year of the car (Which are all stored in the DealershipListing, so i have no problem wiht this part) but I also need to print the address that is stored in the Dealerships table. Can anyone help me with this?

this is what i have for my views.py

```
def store(request):
    dealer_list = Dealer.objects.all()
    car_list = DealershipListing.objects.all()
    context = {'dealer_list': dealer_list, 'car_list': car_list}
    return render(request, 'store/store.html', context)
```

i tried doing

```
{{%for car in car_list%}}
<h6>{{car.year}} {{car.make}} {{car.model}}</h6>
{% endfor %}
```

which works perfectly displaying those. But now how do i display the address of the dealership that is selling the car?

**models.py**

```
class Dealer(models.Model):
    dealersName = models.TextField(('DealersName'))
    zipcode = models.CharField(("zipcodex"), max_length = 15)
    zipcode_2 = models.CharField(("zipCode"), max_length = 15)  
    state = models.CharField(("state"), max_length=5)
    address = models.TextField(("Address"))
    dealerId = models.IntegerField(("ids"), primary_key=True)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dealersName


class DealershipListing(models.Model):
    carID = models.IntegerField(("CarID"), primary_key=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(('price'))
    msrp = models.IntegerField(('msrp'))
    mileage = models.IntegerField(('mileage'))
    is_new = models.BooleanField(('isNew'))
    model = models.CharField(("Models"), max_length= 255)
    make = models.CharField(("Make"), max_length=255)
    year = models.CharField(("Year"),max_length=4)
    dealerID = models.ForeignKey(Dealer, models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.year + " " + self.make + " " + self.model
```

Comment: you can get list cars and list of all dealerships referring to each car in one query using prefetch_related. check https://www.kite.com/python/docs/django.db.models.Prefetch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So then it looks like your question is really `How do I access data from a foreign key in a template?`

The answer is refreshingly simple!

`{{car.dealerID.address}}`

On a side note, you might want to rename `dealerID` to `dealer`, django will handle the db column names how it sees fit, so while you might access the data with `.dealer` the db column would be named `dealer_id` by django automatically. Renaming the field also makes it more obvious that accessing it will give you a dealer and not its id.

Answer (score 1):

calling with the model name is what I prefer to use

```
{{obj.related_table.field_name}}
```

I think this pattern may help you solve problem related to getting related field value